# Android: How to know the receiver had picked up my call programmatic? 

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I want to start timer of Outgoing call when receiver receives my call(accept my call) not at the time of ringing.

for example if i am calling Mr.B then i want acknowledge when Mr.B received my call.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to read state of other phone to which you making call programmatic, you can only read your Phone state not of others!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948961/how-to-know-whether-i-am-in-a-call-on-android/5949116#5949116) is useful answer about phone state.