# How to know whether I am in a call on Android?

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I want to know whether I am in a call.

If I am in a call then start the service (service part is clear). How do I do this?

While attending the call I need to call the service... I am unaware of how to do this? Any help?

Comment: Do you mean in a "phone call", a "method call" or some other call?  (Mating call?  Curtain call?  Lauren Bacall?  :-))

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need broadcast receiver ...

In manifest declare broadcast receiver ...

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>     
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Also declare uses-permission ...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

The broadcast receiver class ...

```
package x.y;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class PhoneStateBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new CustomPhoneStateListener(context), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }

}
```

And one class to customize phone state listener...

```
package x.y;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
    Context context; //Context to make Toast if required 
    public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //when Idle i.e no call
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //when Off hook i.e in call
            //Make intent and start your service here
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Off hook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            //when Ringing
            Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ONE problem  when install this applicaton and phone receives a call...in debug mode the control doesnt come to onReceive

Comment: vaibhav..after CALL_STATE_RINGING:i put system.out.println("rining")i put a breakpoint..and debugged..in phone..i called from another phone...state is ringing..shouldnt the breakpoint get hitted.?it ws not happening so..

Comment: check logcat when first time phone rings case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:it prints logcat once...second call it prints two times...third...its goes like this

Comment: this is because you are leaking listeners.

Comment: what does each of the states mean exactly? off-hook? idle? why can't it be : ringing/addedCall/hangedCall/hangedAll ?

Comment: what if i want to change display name of incoming call on screen?

Comment: it doesn't detect `Phone state Off hook` if app installed on the phone from which you call... it only detects if somebody calls you and you accept...

Comment: starting Android O you need to take in app permission to read Phone State

Answer (score 33):

[`TelephonyManager.getCallState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getCallState%28%29) returns one of

- `CALL_STATE_IDLE`
- `CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK`
- `CALL_STATE_RINGING`

If this fits your requirements, it's much less code than Pied Piper's more comprehensive solution.

Comment: I think it's a much better solution.
In the first case, a new listener is added each phone state change.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that method exist. But this method will be only help if we want to know call state at particular time but it will not help in monitoring phone call states all the time.

Comment: ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getCallState() for newbie

Answer (score 1):

You can only come to know call is coming but you can't modify this. :(
see this 
[why 2.3 version of android does not hava android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE ? and what is the solution for this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416585/why-2-3-version-of-android-does-not-hava-android-permission-modify-phone-state)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, no doubt. But it pops up as the first result on Google. Hence, I decided to add another useful method.

When the phone state is changed, the system sends the `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast. This broadcast has an extra state that can be extracted using `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE`.

The extra state can have three alternatives:

- `EXTRA_STATE_IDLE`
- `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK`
- `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`

You can design a broadcast receiver that will take care of all these:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        if (intent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_CALL_STATE_CHANGED){

            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE){

                // No call currently active.

            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING){

                // A call is ringing

            } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){

                // Call has been answered.

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

**Note:** The broadcast receiver will be triggered in background and as of Android O+, you cannot start a background service from a background process. Consider starting a foreground service with `context.startForegroundService(intent)`. In the `onStartCommand(...)` of the service, call `startForeground(...)`. Otherwise, the system raise a fatal exception. However, below Android O, you can safely use `context.startService(intent)` instead of `startForegroundService(...)`.