# Programmatically dismiss ACTION_VIEW dialog once complete

Tags: java, android, updates

We have a process for allowing our users to manually update the application, because our devices do not have any app store. We download the apk from our servers and run:

```
updateIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
updateIntent.setData(contentUri);
updateIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

with the contentUri pointing to the location of our stored APK. As the installation is running, the app closes. Then, the following screen appears on completion:

[image]

We restart our app immediately when we receive a MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED intent. The issue is that this screen remains in the background.

How can I programmatically dismiss it?

I have tried:

```
// Dismiss all system ui messages
Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
```

but it does not work for this type of dialog

Comment: You mentioned about running on a unique device. Is it a system application in priv-app?

Comment: @Sina no it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT` flag:

```
updateIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);
```

Comment: YES! This does it. I owe you one :)

Answer (score 0):

When your App is installing/updating it come in `stop` state, this is the same state when user go to settings and `force stop` your app. 
So no `service` or `BroadcastReceiver` will work as your app will not be running.

what I suggest you to create 1 more app which will listen to `APP INSTALLATIONS` using BroadcastReceiver and do actions related to that, like whenever the user updates your app using APK it will open the app after installation.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34706932/7948109)

Hope this will help!

Comment: We are successfully restarting the app. That is not the issue. The issue is that the activity view stays in the background.