# customizing incoming call screen in android

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

i am created an app for showing customizing call screen ,using phonsstatelistener.
The screen is having my created pick and end button for answering and rejecting the incoming call respectively.
But,the pick button doesnt work in **android Version 2.3+** giving Secuirty Exception.

Please provide any other way out of showing data on the phone incoming call screen in android

Comment: what you have tried? Some code will be good. And also post your logcat.

Comment: I use phonestatelistener to pick the event of phone Ringing and it shows the data along with pickup and reject button.The pick button shows following in android2.3+ 03-05 13:43:08.877: W/System.err(497): java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10035 nor current process has android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
03-05 13:43:08.877: W/System.err(497):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
03-05 13:43:08.877: W/System.err(497):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)

Comment: have you added this in your manifest?? If not try this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: yes,i have added that in my manifest file ,my apps works perfectly on android 2.2 but gives error only in android 2.3+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more useful demo please check this one :

[show the information in the middle of the call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683841/show-the-information-in-the-middle-of-the-call)

Maybe this will help you to some extent.

And also check this link for exception :

[How to grant MODIFY_PHONE_STATE permission for apps ran on Gingerbread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715250/how-to-grant-modify-phone-state-permission-for-apps-ran-on-gingerbread)

Comment: thanks ,now i use a toast to show the message on incuming screen

Comment: what if i want to change display name of incoming call on screen?