# Android app in unrooted phone and telephony API usage

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Is it possible using the telephony (or other) APIs on an unrooted Android phone, for an application to listen for the Telephony intents (ringing / Incoming-call), and if calling party matches a criteria (such as, from a black-list), disconnect the call, without requiring a confirmation by the user ?

Also, it is possible for an application on such (an unrooted) Android phone to initiate an outgoing call without user's intervention (s.a. at a particular time or when certain conditions are met) ?

In my research so far, I've found that I'd have to use a BroadcastReceiver with the right priority, to be able to "trap" the 'ringing event', and use `ITelephony.aidl` to reject the call. However, it wasn't clear if I can do the latter on an unrooted phone or not.

For the second requirement, it is not clear if app can make an going call -- again, on an unrooted Android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible using the telephony (or other) APIs on an unrooted Android phone, for an application to listen for the Telephony intents (ringing / Incoming-call), and if calling party matches a criteria (such as, from a black-list), disconnect the call, without requiring a confirmation by the user ?

You can easily [get the state of the current call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5949116/1069068). However, hanging up yourself without user interaction is only possible through reflection.

> Also, it is possible for an application on such (an unrooted) Android phone to initiate an outgoing call without user's intervention (s.a. at a particular time or when certain conditions are met) ?

You can dial a number without asking the user by using:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Keep in mind that you must have the `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission, and that replacing `ACTION_CALL` with `ACTION_DIAL` will ask the user to confirm. `ACTION_CALL` places the call directly.