# Android : Customizing view when user getting call?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, phone-call

Hi friends I'm developing android application here I want to set image, accept button, cancel button when user getting call.

I can't able to find any tutorial related. Suggest me any tutorial. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

when you need to do something when you get a call, you have to detect when you get a call There are some constants in [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_RINGING). 
by using this constant we can detect when a call is ringing, see the code 
TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING.

```
 if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){  

      // do what ever u want here.
   }
```

Here is the complete [Tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-call-state-example)

this is not a complete answer hope this may get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Please look into the following answer.
[How to know whether I am in a call on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948961/how-to-know-whether-i-am-in-a-call-on-android)

You have to call your customized view in `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` that case and perform a action as per your requirement.

Hope it will helps you.