# How do i detect phone call?

Tags: android, apk

I am just starting my adventure with android and I would like to do something like that when someone calls or rings, I put in a "TOAST" and an exemplary inscription.
I used the code from: https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee

My code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.arek.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

java/com.example.arek.test/MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.arek.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Toast.makeText(context, "This is my Toast message!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

java/com.example.arek.test/PhonecallReceiver.java

```
package com.example.arek.test;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public abstract class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    //The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        }
        else{
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            }
            else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }


            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    }

    //Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    //Deals with actual events

    //Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
    //Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change, debounce extras
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                savedNumber = number;
                onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                    onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                    onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                else{
                    onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }
}
```

java/com.example.arek.test/CallReceiver.java

```
package com.example.arek.test;

import java.util.Date;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "Dzwonie 1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "Test 2",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "Test 3",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "Test 4",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx.getApplicationContext(), "Test 5",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

The application works but if you call or call someone, there is no TOAST (test *). Please, help me :)

Comment: Is there some `Exception` or nothing ?

Comment: nothing, but can I find it? (android studio)

Comment: First of all, debug your code. And check what's the problem ?

Comment: i debug but is all ok

Comment: Where are you using your `CallReceiver`.

Comment: If the device is 6.0, it may not work. You may need `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE`. Please see the comment from your gist link (https://gist.github.com/ftvs/e61ccb039f511eb288ee#gistcomment-1988423)

Comment: Possible duplicated? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563921/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-an-android-device

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments!

Answer:

I add line in:AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

For Android 5.1 everything works! :)
For Android 7.0 you must manually give permissions on your phone (settings/apps etc)

Thanks :)

Comment: Didn't you get an error saying that it is a protected permission?

Comment: I'm not sure why that permission is being asked here, because the code seems to do what I can already do and I don't need that permission. Why not this, for example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948961/how-to-know-whether-i-am-in-a-call-on-android. Only needs READ_PHONE_STATE. I've also yet to understand what the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE actually allows us to do... If I could use it to know the exact state, like on hold, active,.... But no.... (or at least I don't find anywhere talking about that).