# Embed custom voice with user voice in system active call in android

Tags: android, voice, android-phone-call

I have got all call states through this    [refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948961/how-to-know-whether-i-am-in-a-call-on-android/5949116#5949116)

but now i want to add my custom voice from my app in user active call with user voice.

can android gives me such a permission to do so ?

if android OS gives permission then how can i embed my voice (can be mp3 or something) with user voice.

Please help me in this scenerio.